# Twitch Embed with Korean Streamer Name

Tags: reactjs, api, twitch

i'm actually working on a **Twitch clone with React**, using the Twitch API.

I've barely finished my project but I have a problem with my embed, when it's a non-latin alphabet name, like "한동숙" **it's not working.**

I am embedding twitch with this *handy tool* : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitch-embed-video

And it looks like this :

```
import React from "react";
import './Live.css';
import ReactTwitchEmbedVideo from "react-twitch-embed-video"


function Live({location }){


    return(

        <div className="containerLive">
            <ReactTwitchEmbedVideo height="927" width="100%" channel={location.state.name} />
        </div>

    )
}

export default Live;
```

I am taking the name from location and place it in the channel, it work fine with **latin alphabet name.**

I know there is also the twitch embed, but it's not easy to use with react **and the problem is the same :**

```
<body>   <!-- Add a placeholder for the Twitch embed -->
    <div id="twitch-embed"></div>

    <!-- Load the Twitch embed script -->
    <script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>

    <!-- Create a Twitch.Embed object that will render within the "twitch-embed" root element. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: 854,
        height: 480,
        channel: "한동숙" // <-- Not Working !
      });
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Unfortunatly there is no way to display stream with user_id, just user_name ...

DO i need translate it in some way ? How twitch can display asian stream ?

*Thank's if someone is passing by, there is litteraly no questions on that topic.*

Comment: Make sure your charset is UTF-8. Also on your code editor, check if your file encoding is UTF-8 too.

Comment: Yep charset and file encoding is UTF-8 ...

Comment: I don't have any problem outputting korean in codesandbox so I'm not really sure what's the problem, can you check if you can see the korean text here. If you can't, it might be a browser problem. https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-violet-m8ojd

Comment: The problem is not the display, the problem is the Twitch Embed that don't recognize this writing. Test the Embed with an Asian Streamer and it won't work.

Comment: I found a solution, the api provide a "login" and if we pass it, it's working somehow ... Thank's for your time :)

Comment: Cheers man, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should use "name" field instead "display_name".
Name = login. It's always latinian alphabet.

Hope i helped you.